# When installing kabanero-foundation, does "Waiting for KnativeServing knative-serving to be ready." have a time-out?

Tags: kabanero

Installing on OpenShift4.2 3x3 Cluster using install script posted on https://github.com/kabanero-io/kabanero-foundation. The following block is echoed for last 1.5 hours

```
echo 'Waiting for KnativeServing knative-serving to be ready.'
Waiting for KnativeServing knative-serving to be ready.
++ oc get knativeserving knative-serving -n knative-serving '--output=jsonpath={.status.conditions[-1:].type}'
+ TYPE=Ready
++ oc get knativeserving knative-serving -n knative-serving '--output=jsonpath={.status.conditions[-1:].status}'
+ STATUS=False
+ sleep 2
+ '[' False == True ']'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a timeout - the install script will continue to wait until the `KnativeServing` instance is ready.  This can take a considerable amount of time on some systems (15-30 minutes).  However 1.5 hours is excessive.

There is a known bug with Kabanero 0.3.0 (https://github.com/kabanero-io/kabanero-operator/issues/317) which is not compatible with recent versions of OpenShift Container Platform 4.2.  Specifically, not compatible with the OpenShift Serverless operator v1.2.0.  This has been addressed in Kabanero 0.3.1 (https://github.com/kabanero-io/kabanero-operator/releases/tag/0.3.1).  That might explain why the install script continues to loop for you - the KnativeServing instance would never be ready.